# creating my first nodejs,mongo, express angularjs app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I am setting up my first angularjs webapp using nodejs.
The one part i am not sure how to do is how to include my angularapp.js in my index.html?

currently i have

```
/public
    index.html
    /javascript
          webapp.js ( my angular app js file)
/routes
    myroute.js       

app.js (my nodejs app )
```

my myroute.js has and it loads fine

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   res.sendFile(path.resolve('public/index.html'));
});
```

the problem is that i am note sure how to load my webapp.js
in my index.html i have

```
<script src = "/public/javascript/webapp.js"></script>
```

And this does not load. So what is the best way to do this. Should i create 
a route for everything in /public/javascript/

how do other people do this or what is the best practice

thanks for any help

update....
i added the following to myroute.js

```
router.get(/javascript/, function(req, res, next){
       res.sendFile(path.resolve('public/javascript/webapp.js'));
});
```

and the javscript file now loads but this is not the way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it now. I've been searching and looks like for security reasons you need to serve the javascripts and other files you wish to allow access to as static files. On app.js add this :

```
app.use("/static",express.static(__dirname+"/public/javascript"));
```

Where "static" is just a virtual path you create for an specific folder. Then  change src on script:

```
http://localhost:port/static/webapp.js
```

or

```
/static/webapp.js
```

It worked for me
For more details you should check this out:
http://expressjs.com/es/starter/static-files.html

Comment: This did not work. Still got 404. Updated the description with a little more debug info

Comment: Look. I got the answer @randy